# how to fix the CrudRepository.save(java.lang.Object) is no accessor method in springboot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

im reffering to this `springboot` tutorial and im using `spring data` in my project, im trying to add `data to database` . using the following `.` bt when im trying to do that i get an error saying

> Invoked method public abstract java.lang.Object
>   org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository.save(java.lang.Object)
>   is no accessor method!

here is my code ,

```
//my controller

@RequestMapping("/mode")
    public String showProducts(ModeRepository repository){
        Mode m = new Mode();
        m.setSeats(2);
        repository.save(m); //this is where the error getting from
        return "product";
    }


//implementing crud with mode repository
@Repository
public interface ModeRepository extends CrudRepository<Mode, Long> {

}

 //my mode class
@Entity
@Table(name="mode")
public class Mode implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private int idMode; 


    @Column(nullable=false)
    private int seats;

    //assume that there are getters and setters
}
```

im new to `springboot` and can someone tellme what am i doing wrong,
appreciate if someone could provide me a link to get to know about `springdata`
other than `spring documentation`

Comment: how do you inject repository into controller?

Comment: `showProducts(ModeRepository repository)` - as a argument inside the method which i think will be autowired

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change your controller code so that the ModeRepository is a private autowired field.

```
    @Autowired //don't forget the setter
    private ModeRepository repository; 

    @RequestMapping("/mode")
    public String showProducts(){
        Mode m = new Mode();
        m.setSeats(2);
        repository.save(m); //this is where the error getting from
        return "product";
    }
```

Comment: Wow, that actually woked, bt why am i not supposed to get the `dependency` passed from the `method parameter` thanks !

Comment: usually controller method arguments are used to pass the model (parsed http request) to the controller logic

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this error today. IntelliJ IDEA told me that direct field injection is discouraged, what makes sense in a way. You can also use constructor injection on a @Controller. Might look like overhead but I think it's more clean.

```
@Controller
public class WhateverController {

    private ModeRepository repository;

    public WhateverController(ModeRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/mode")
    public String showProducts(){
        Mode m = new Mode();
        m.setSeats(2);
        repository.save(m); //this is where the error getting from
        return "product";
    }    
}
```